# microsoft access query builder custom date format

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, date-format, query-builder, formatdatetime

In the query builder for an unbound field I need:
=SiInm(Condition";Format([Fecha];format1);Format([Fecha];format2))
I have my condition, what I need is that format1 return something like this: 22 de Abril de 2015, and format2 return: April 22, 2015.

format1 in Spanish, day ´de´ month ´de´ year

format2 in English, month day, year

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The first is simple:

```
format1 = "d \d\e mmmm \d\e yyyy"
```

For the second you'll need a function that return the English month names for a month value:

```
=SiInm(Condition;Format([Fecha];"d \d\e mmmm \d\e yyyy");GetEnglishMonthName(Month([Fecha])) & Format([Fecha];" d, yyyy"))
```